# OkHttp Request in Separate Class

Tags: java, android, get, okhttp

So I currently have my OkHttp requests in my MainActivity in order to test that they actually worked. However, I need to move them to a separate class so that I can use the requests to populate my Navagation Drawer menu items. Furthermore, in my MainActivity, I do oAuth of invalidating a token and requesting it and that token needs to be used in my requests. I am a bit lost as I am calling the new class in my MainActivity as `apiRequest.run();` This is what I get back in the run console.

```
I/System.out: ya29.CjBIAx67rM70-CKu9Wc5fUSLzt9rIqt4bRubpl4hB9UjwqeRatoZppbMmNDl_SPcFWA
E/AuthApp: ya29.CjBIAx67rM70-CKu9Wc5fUSLzt9rIqt4bRubpl4hB9UjwqeRatoZppbMmNDl_SPcFWA
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String android.content.SharedPreferences.getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
W/System.err:     at com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.AuthPreferences.getToken(AuthPreferences.java:43)
W/System.err:     at com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.APIRequests.run(APIRequests.java:34)
W/System.err:     at com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:90)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.onClick(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10814)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Here is my MainActivity where I am implementing it.

```
Context mContext = MainActivity.this;
    private AccountManager mAccountManager;
    private AuthPreferences authPreferences;
    private APIRequests apiRequests;
    EditText emailText;
    TextView responseView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    static final String API_URL = "https://api.comma.ai/v1/auth/?access_token=";
    static final String ChffrMe_URL = "https://api.comma.ai/v1/me/";
    static final String SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me";
    private static final int AUTHORIZATION_CODE = 1993;
    private static final int ACCOUNT_CODE = 1601;
    String commatoken;
    String commaMyInfo;
    private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        responseView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.responseView);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mAccountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
        authPreferences = new AuthPreferences(this);
        apiRequests = new APIRequests();
        final Context context = this;
        invalidateToken();
        requestToken();
        SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (authPreferences.getUser() != null && authPreferences.getToken() != null) {
                    System.out.println(authPreferences.getToken());
                    doCoolAuthenticatedStuff();
//                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NavDrawerActivity.class);
//                    startActivity(intent);
                    try {
                        apiRequests.run();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
//                    try {
//                        run();
//                    } catch (Exception e) {
//                        e.printStackTrace();
//                    }
                    //new RetrieveFeedTask().execute();
                } else {
                    chooseAccount();
                }
            }
        });
```

And here is my APIRequests.java

```
public class APIRequests {
    private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    static final String API_URL = "https://api.comma.ai/v1/auth/?access_token=";
    static final String ChffrMe_URL = "https://api.comma.ai/v1/me/";
    private AuthPreferences authPreferences = new AuthPreferences(this);
    String commatoken;
    String commaMyInfo;
    private MainActivity mActivity;

    public void run() throws Exception {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(API_URL + authPreferences.getToken())
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

                Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
                for (int i = 0, size = responseHeaders.size(); i < size; i++) {
                    System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
                }
                try
                {
                    String token = response.body().string();
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(token);
                    commatoken = json.getString("access_token");
                } catch (JSONException e)
                {

                }
//                commatoken = response.body().string();
//                System.out.println(commatoken);

                if(response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    final Request dataRequest = new Request.Builder()
                            .header("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                            .header("authorization", "JWT "+ commatoken)
                            .url(ChffrMe_URL).build();

                    client.newCall(dataRequest).enqueue(new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call call, Response responseMe) throws IOException {
                            if (!responseMe.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + responseMe);

                            Headers responseHeaders = responseMe.headers();
                            for (int i = 0, size = responseHeaders.size(); i < size; i++) {
                                System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
                            }
                            try
                            {
                                String myInfo = responseMe.body().string();
                                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(myInfo);
                                commaMyInfo = json.getString("points");
                                System.out.println(commaMyInfo);
                            } catch (JSONException e)
                            {

                            }
//                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
//                                @Override
//                                public void run() {
//                                    responseView.setText("Comma Points: " +commaMyInfo);
//                                }
//                            });

                        }
                    });
                }
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Not sure why it isn't liking my apiRequests.run();

Here is the AuthPreferences

```
public class AuthPreferences {
    private static final String KEY_USER = "user";
    private static final String KEY_TOKEN = "token";

    private SharedPreferences preferences;

    public AuthPreferences(Context context) {
        preferences = context
                .getSharedPreferences("auth", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public AuthPreferences(APIRequests apiRequests) {

    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(KEY_USER, user);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void setToken(String password) {
        Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(KEY_TOKEN, password);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return preferences.getString(KEY_USER, null);
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return preferences.getString(KEY_TOKEN, null);

    }
}
```

Comment: `at com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.AuthPreferences.getToken(AuthPreferences.java:43)` -- your problem is in `AuthPreferences`.

Comment: Am I calling it correctly in my APIRequests.java? Authpreferences is used in my MainActivity as well because that is where I get my token. So I guess I should grab the token from MainActivity instead of implementing a new AuthPreferences in my APIRequests?

Comment: "Am I calling it correctly in my APIRequests.java?" -- I have no way of knowing, as you did not include `AuthPreferences.java` in your question. However, I find it rather suspicious that you are creating an instance by passing in an `APIRequests` to the constructor. In the activity, you pass the activity into the constructor. Perhaps you should pass the `AuthPreferences` instance from the activity to `APIRequests`, rather than create a new instance.

Comment: I have included the `AuthPreferences`. And right, so pass the authPreferences.getToken(); to APIRequests.java? If so, how would that look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AuthPreferences` class has two constructors. One sets a `preferences` field. The other does not. You crash when you use the constructor that does not set the `preferences` field, as then that field is `null` when you try using it.

I recommend getting rid of the second constructor. Then, add a constructor to `APIRequests` that takes an `AuthPreferences` as a parameter, and use that to populate the `authPreferences` field (rather than creating a new, flawed instance of `AuthPreferences`). Then, in the activity, replace `apiRequests = new APIRequests();` with `apiRequests = new APIRequests(authPreferences);`, to meet the requirements of your new constructor.

Comment: It isn't crashing, it just isn't getting to the APIRequests run for some reason because I am not seeing the System.out.println(commaMyInfo); Would you suggestion fix that?

Comment: @JamesRobertSingleton: "It isn't crashing" -- um, the stack trace in your question indicates otherwise.

Comment: I should clarify and say that the app itself isn't crashing. It just stays at the activity_main

Comment: @JamesRobertSingleton: "the app itself isn't crashing" -- again, the stack trace in your question indicates otherwise. Specifically, you crash when the user clicks the button.

Comment: Weird, since when I click the button nothing happens but that shows up in the run console haha. 

Are you talking about  `public AuthPreferences(APIRequests apiRequests)` to replace? And also put `public APIRequests(AuthPreferences authPreferences)` in my APIRequests.java?

Comment: @JamesRobertSingleton: "Are you talking about public AuthPreferences(APIRequests apiRequests) to replace?" -- yes. "And also put public APIRequests(AuthPreferences authPreferences) in my APIRequests.java? " -- yes.

Comment: Gotcha, and then get rid of `private AuthPreferences authPreferences = new AuthPreferences(this);` too?

Comment: But still not sure what to put in ` public APIRequests(AuthPreferences authPreferences)`

Comment: @JamesRobertSingleton: Quoting my answer: "Then, add a constructor to APIRequests that takes an AuthPreferences as a parameter, and use that to populate the authPreferences field (rather than creating a new, flawed instance of AuthPreferences)." So, your constructor has `this.authPreferences=authPreferences`, to assign a value to your `authPreferences` field using the `authPreferences` constructor parameter.

Comment: Ahh I needed to add `private final AuthPreferences authPreferences;` up top then add `this.authPreferences = authPreferences` inside my public APIRequests(AuthPreferences authPreferences)

Comment: So am I going to have to do something similar in my NavDrawer as well?

Comment: @JamesRobertSingleton: I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: Ok, no worries. Thank you though!

Comment: so you know how I have the JSONObjects saved to a variable? Would there be a way to grab that variable in another class?

Comment: @JamesRobertSingleton: Not the way you have things written at present. `run()` probably should take some sort of listener or callback, on which it calls a method to provide the results of your HTTP call.

Comment: each newCall though is a new Callback()?